# Convert single page from PDF to JPEG and getting error: `no matches found: Binder3.pdf[12]`

Tags: pdf, convert, zsh, imagemagick

I want to convert single page from 333 PDF pages file.

I have tried with this command: `convert Binder3.pdf[12] image.jpg`, but for some reason I am getting this error:

> zsh: no matches found: Binder3.pdf[12]

The name of the file is correct. I double check it. Why is it not working? I am using ***ImageMagick 6.9.10-8 Q16 x86_64 20180723***

Comment: it worked. can u post it as an answer?

Comment: yes I am using `zsh` thanks it worked this way as well!

Comment: Please see answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[12]` is a shell glob expression - in the default `bash` shell, if it doesn't match anything in the current directory, then the string `Binder3.pdf[12]` will be passed unmolested to the `convert` program, however in `zsh` the default is to error out on `nomatch` (equivalent to the `bash` `failglob` shell option).

You can get bash-like behavior in zsh by setting `setopt +o nomatch` however this may result in unexpected behavior if there *is* a glob match - it's better to force the shell (whichever one) to treat the characters literally e.g.

```
convert Binder3.pdf\[12\] image.jpg
```

or

```
convert "Binder3.pdf[12]" image.jpg
```

Comment: and if i set `setopt +o nomatch` to unset it i need to execute `setopt -o nomatch`?

Comment: @Dimitar yes that's correct